# External, dynamically loaded SVG: Can't access Elements with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, svg

I am programming a digital advent calendar for a client. This thing where you can open a little door every day until christmas. Here is my problem:
I have 24 svgs where every day one more door is open and you can click on "todays" door to open it. So i have overlays in the svgs which trigger a modal where the content is dynamically loaded.

Also the SVG itselfs needs to be dynamically loaded since it is a new one every day. When i run it locally everything works fine but i need to implement it into the customers Webflow.com environment. The svgs are stored on my own server. As soon as i load it in the webflow environment i cannot access the elements inside the svg anymore. I guess this is because it is not loaded into the DOM properly. I can't find any solution.

So this is the code block that i embed into the webflow page:

```
<div class="backgroundcontainer">
    <object class="backgroundimage" data="" id="background" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
</div>
```

then via javascript i add the image:

```
let bgImage = document.getElementById('background');
if (bgDay >= 25) {
    bgImage.data = "MYSERVER/assets/images/bg/25.svg"
} else {
    bgImage.data = "MYSERVER/assets/images/bg/" + bg;
}
```

`bg` is "today".svg

locally this works to add the click listener to the 24 "doors" (with ids 1-24 within the svg) which are defined in the svg:

```
bgImage.addEventListener('load', function () {
    let bgContent = bgImage.contentDocument;

    for (let i = 1; i <= today; i++) {
        let door = bgContent.getElementById(i);
        door.style.cursor = 'zoom-in';
        door.setAttribute('id', i.toString())
        door.addEventListener('click', function () {
            openModal(i)
        })
    }
})
```

in webflow `bgImage.contentDocument` returns `null`

any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Probably a CORS related issue - check your dev tools console: can you see any logs like "Unsafe attempt to load URL"? You might solve the problem by explicitly setting  a [CORS header for your server](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Comment: Because it is a background image? Try a simple test putting it into a div as an image